# Sequelize - get fields in database

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The `Model.rawAttributes` returns the list of fields defined in [sequelize.define()](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-define) method. However, I want to check the fields for a particular model once the table has been created in the database. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check for a particular field in the Model? or a Model that is associated to it?

Comment: @r9119 I want to check for a particular field in the model

Comment: Models are classes cant you just `model.field != null` to check if it exists in the model? Another way would be to use `field.in(Model.rawAttributes)`